# MEF Execute Plugin Exports in Threads

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, plugin, chat

I am developing a service application that would implement a peer to peer messaging system. I am wondering if my following code is the best approach. It works, but I am naive and it would be nice to have validation from experts for performance and reliability.

There would be about 5 plugins and a large number of messages (over 100,000 in a day. Each message could be upto 1000 characters) may be generated by each plugin and communicated to each other based on some logic.

The following are the MEFContracts -

```
namespace MEFContracts{

//peer to peer message transmissions.  Any plugin or core can transmit messages to one another
public interface IPeerMessage
{
void ReceiveMessage(string message,string from,string to);
}

//Core application starts a thread on the following exported plugin function
public interface IExecuteThread
{
void ExecuteThread();
}
}
```

The following is the Core application export -

```
namespace MEFCore{
[Export(typeof(IPeerMessage))]
[ExportMetadata("MEFName", "Core")]

class MEFExports:IPeerMessage
{

public void ReceiveMessage(string message, string from, string to)
{
    log.Info("Message Received by Core :" + message + from + to);
}
}
}
```

The following is each plugin code.

```
namespace MEFPlugin{
[Export(typeof(IPeerMessage))]
[ExportMetadata("MEFName", "PlugIn")]
[Export(typeof(IExecuteThread))]

public class MEFPluginExports : IPeerMessage, IExecuteThread
{
[ImportMany]
public System.Lazy<IPeerMessage,
IDictionary<string, object>>[] _peerMessageComponents
{ get; set; }

public void ReceiveMessage(string message, string from, string to)
{
    log.Info("Message Received by Plugin:" + message + " " + from + " " + to);
}

public void ExecuteThread()
{
//The core application starts this thread which generates messages.  It then transmits these messages to the various parts based on the MEFName attribute 
while(true) //I will implement later a way for the core to stop the thread when the service is stopped
{
   //generate message
   //Determine the part to communicate to, say _core

    _core.ReceiveMessage("Hello Core", "PlugIn", "Core");

}
}
```

And the following is the main core service

```
[ImportMany]
public System.Lazy<IPeerMessage,
IDictionary<string, object>>[] _peerMessageComponents
{ get; set; }
[ImportMany(typeof(IExecuteThread))]
public IEnumerable<IExecuteThread> _pluginThreads { get; set; }


public void Process()
{
    log.Info("MEFCoreService started");
    AssembleMEFComponents();

     foreach(IExecuteThread _pluginThread in _pluginThreads)
    {
        Thread _thread = new Thread(_pluginThread.ExecuteThread));
        _thread.Start();
        _thread.Join();

    }

}

public void AssembleMEFComponents()
{
    try
    {
        //Creating an instance of aggregate catalog. It aggregates other catalogs
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        //Build the directory path where the parts will be available
       //using the directory catalog
        var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll");

        //Load parts from the current assembly 
        var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //Add to the aggregate catalog
        aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);
        aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCatalog);

        //Crete the composition container
        var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

        // Composable parts are created here 
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately the indention of your code is totally off. Fixing this will help reviewers to do their job.

Answer (score 1):

Only a quick shot at **AssembleMEFComponents()** method

- declare your variables as near to their usage as possible.
- using `try..catch` like you do is not only superfluous but also **breaks the stacktrace**.
- comments like `//Add to the aggregate catalog` are superfluous too. Comments should describe **why** something is done in the way it is done. **What** is done should be described by the code itself by using meaningful and descriptive name for methods, variables and classes.

That being said your method should look like so

```
public void AssembleMEFComponents()
{

    var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll");

    var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);
    aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(assemblyCatalog );

    var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

    container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments.  I have not seen many examples of starting MEF plugin code in a thread on the core application.  Is that proper ?  Do you suggest any other way to run plugin code ?

Comment: Basically I don't use MEF at all.